# JSON.NET Deserialization with VB.NET/ASP.NET - Frustrating

Tags: .net, json, vb.net, json.net, deserialization

I have a feeling i'm making just a small oversight here and I think a second (or third) pair of eyes could help work it out. Here is what I have done:

1. Made a request to a webservice
2. Received the JSON response from that webservice
3. Read that JSON into a string

The string successfully contains the JSON output. However, this is where things get difficult. I've created a public class into which I want to cast my deserialized JSON. However, when I try to cast the JSON string into a class (using JSON.NET) I receive the following error.

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type  m      'Sandbox.youtube+Item' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
```

The JSON looks something like this:

```
{
"kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
"etag": "\"Fn7tolrWrLXf7uknBpwCU9OfMA8/AgytE2CN3Aj3J6OFJ5iDqg8-Hbw\"",
"pageInfo": {
 "totalResults": 1000000,
 "resultsPerPage": 50
     },
  "nextPageToken": "CDIQAA",
  "items": [
   {
  "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"Fn7tolrWrLXf7uknBpwCU9OfMA8/mQk0CDCRDq-8Xy5YSW9FLLA7B3g\"",
   "id": {
"kind": "youtube#video",
"videoId": "BJ2q017EL08"
}
 }
```

(I may have missed a few brackets when copying / pasting across)

My public class looks like this:

```
Public Class Rootobject

    Public Property kind As String
    Public Property etag As String
    Public Property pageInfo As Pageinfo
    Public Property nextPageToken As String
    Public Property items() As Item
End Class

Public Class Pageinfo
    Public Property totalResults As Integer
    Public Property resultsPerPage As Integer
End Class

Public Class Item
    Public Property kind As String
    Public Property etag As String
    Public Property id As Idprop
End Class

Public Class Idprop
    Public Property kind As String
    Public Property videoId As String
End Class
```

and I attempt to cast like this:

```
Dim ent As Rootobject = TryCast(Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Rootobject)(webresponse), Rootobject)
```

**Any ideas are REALLY appreciated!**

All the best,
Jordan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
Public Property items() As Item
```

to this:

```
Public Property items As List(Of Item)
```